# jQuery/Javascript confirm coming up twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

For some weird reason i'm getting my confirm box coming up twice. here is my code:

```
$(".DeleteComment").live("click", function(){

    var CommentID = $(this).attr("rel");
    var confirm

    if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete this comment?')){

        return false;

    }else{
        $(this).html("loading").css("color", "#999");
        //AJAX HERE
        return false;
    }


});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you load any content dynamically (via ajax)?  It could be the case that the click event is bound to the same element twice resulting in the double confirmation.

Answer (score 5):

It happens when we bind event on the elements which are **loaded dynamically via AJAX**

So for example we are loading some dynamic html content (e.g. dynamic content in modal) on click of the `edit` form button,

And in that content if we have **binded click event on some button** e.g. `delete` button, then every time we click on `edit` form button, **it binds the `click` event to `delete` button every time,**

And if you have set confirm box on click event of `delete` button then, **it will ask you as many time as it was binded for that click event** means here if we have clicked `edit` form button 5 times then it will asks for your confirmation 5 times.

So for solving that issue **you can `unbind` the event every time before binding event** to dynamically loaded element as following :

```
$(document).off('click', '.DeleteComment').on('click', '.DeleteComment', function () {
   if (confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete this comment?')){
      //Delete process
      return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Or **Another way to solve this problem is to add your script in main page, means static page not in dynamically loaded one**.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
$_blockDelete = false;

$(".DeleteComment").live("click", function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    //event.stopPropagation(); // it is not necessary

    if (!$_blockDelete)
    {
      $_blockDelete  =true;
      var rconfirm = confirm('Are you sure you want to permanently delete this comment?');
      if (rconfirm)
      {
          $(this).html("loading").css("color", "#999");
          var CommentID = $(this).attr("rel");
          //AJAX HERE
          //return the value "false" the variable "$_blockDelete" once again ajax response

      }
    }

});
```

Comment: from jQuery doc on stopPropagation() "Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running" so if "click" is bound twice the confirm dialog will still show up twice.

Comment: ok, I agree with you that in this case would not be useful. better to leave the example modify the script.

Comment: Is return false necessary?

Comment: @billrichards yes, because it need the default action of the event will not be triggered. but is better use event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing that not-used `var confirm`?