# JavaScript: Confirm in MVC3's PartialView doesn't close

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, confirm

I have a problem with the JS's confirm in my PartialView. The code below works fine if the page is NOT a PartialView, but, if the page IS a PartialView, if I click OK on that confirm dialog it does not close. Why ?

```
$("input.del-file-cb").live('click',function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          var ans = confirm('Are You sure ?');

          if (ans) {
                   ....             
          } else {
                 $(this).attr("checked", false);
          }
      }
 });
```

### Edit

It looks that it is a double confirmation... like here [jQuery/Javascript confirm coming up twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801164/jquery-javascript-confirm-coming-up-twice)

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
$("input.del-file-cb").live('click',function (e) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         e.preventDefault();

... the rest of the code ...
```